# PHP get hash URL in wordpress with Javascript Ajax Magic

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to change meta and title depending on the search query. My search results are starting with a hash tag, so it's seems hard to get it with php. I followed some tutorials:

/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/js/hash.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        $.get('/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/php/ajax-hash.php', { tag: hash },
            function(data) { $('#tag').html(data); }
        );
    });
});
```

/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/php/ajax-hash.php

```
<?php
    $ajaxhashurl = isset($_GET['tag']) ? $_GET['tag'] : 'none';
?>
```

/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php

```
function hash_tracking() {
    if( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'hash_tracker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/js/hash.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hash_tracking' );

add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_search_wpseo_title');
function filter_search_wpseo_title($title) {
    if(  is_front_page() ) {
        include '/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/php/ajax-hash.php';

        if (strpos($ajaxhashurl,'"2":"200"') !== false) {
            $title = 'Something';
        }
            return $title;
}}
```

This however doesn't seems to be working and also breaks my page. the page itself is here - https://sochi.asp.sale

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At you callback, where you do `function(data) { $('#tag').html(data); }` change to:

```
function(data) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = data; 
}
```

Also, there is no element with id "tag" at the page you provided.

Comment: Actually, it seems I followed a wrong tutorial for tags. I don't have any hash tags on the page itself. I only have hash value in the link. I need to think of changing the code completly.